# Choppy playback of HD video on Jellybean

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, video, bugs, 4.1-jelly-bean

I run Jellybean on my Galaxy Nexus, and ever since I switched from ICS I've started getting choppy playback of HD video. I used to be able to watch 720p video without any problem in MX Player. If I switch to software rendering instead of hardware in MX player it improves somewhat, but it's still choppy at least every other minute or so until it recovers. If I play it in the VLC beta I get artifacts every now and then until it works itself out.

Anyone recognize this issue and has any idea what to do about it?

Comment: Read my post again. It says "If I play it in the VLC beta I get artifacts every now and then until it works itself out."

Comment: you're right, oversaw that. Maybe just wait until there's  a better version than the leaked dev preview. There's no source and no *real* hacker devs involved with this ROM. So no one really cares who might have the skills. , I guess that's why your question over at XDA also didn't receive quality answers (yet): http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1749589

Comment: Agreed with this -- chances are that the official Google ROM update for Jelly Bean will offer better performance. JB hasn't been released to AOSP yet, but once it is, I'm sure we'll see major software improvements.